# Data visualization using Dynamic Paint /Particle System

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

I would like to visualize my Data in a efficient and individual style.

My Data is in form of a .CSV file and consists of 700000 data sets.
(later i want about 20 million to be visualized)

One dataset has three information: Longitude (X-Coordinate), Latitude (Y-Coordinate) and a Timelinevalue (Z-Axis).

I managed to create a vertex-cloud using the CSV-Mesh-Importer
[Blenderartists CSV-Mesh-Importer](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?211735-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-Meshes-%28for-Blender-2-5x-or-later%29).
The result is one object with my 700000 vertices...... So far so good.
But to make some kind of Infographic i want to use Dynamic Paint.

In the next step I:

- animated  my cloud and pushed it through a plane (linear movement on Z-Axis).
- subdivided my plane and set it to  Dynamic-Paint Canvas
- set my vertices to Dynamic-Paint Brush
- set Dynamic Paint Source to Proximity
- Dynamic Paint Source - Paint Distance to 0.1

....no Result

If only i could set the Paint source to vertices.... ;-)

I had to convert all vertices into little triangles or rectangles (extrude 2x)

With the quadruple number of vertices i got a visualization.
....Not really satisfying

- Is it possible to convert my datacloud into a Particle System?
- Can I teach Dynamic Paint to read out the vertices of the object?
- Should i try another solution?

Thanks

Silent_Bob
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate 'individual style'?

Comment: Sure.
With ´individual´ i mean the visual outputs Dynamic-Paint offers: 
-Paints
-Displacements
-Heatmaps
-Use of Color-Ramps
-Dissolving Paint

Answer (score 1):

From description it's quite hard for me to understand if your question is a goal of your needs or only if your question covers your vision - to get something you know about it.

> Is it possible to convert my datacloud into a Particle System?

Yes.

- Create "New" particle system with your point cloud (brush) object selected
- Setup the number of particles same as vertices of your "brush" object
- Set Emit from "Verts" (uncheck "Random")
- "Physics" set to "No"
- In "Render" panel of particles properties check on "Unborn" and "Died"

From how many vertices point cloud consist? Just select object and see header of blender window (next to the logo - "Vert:").

- From your screen it looks like vertices represents some volume. For
  that you can visualized vertices with new "Point Density" node. Check
  this part of video https://youtu.be/GhwzIQ6qZO8?t=464
- If you'r looking for a way to convert your point cloud into a mesh
  search for remesh  or point cloud skinning.